# Is it possible to model hBN spin defects/plasmons coupling in COMSOL/Lumerical

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spin, plasmonics

Hexagonal Boron Nitride (h-BN) is a promising material for Quantum technologies, see [[1]](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.nanolett.1c02495). I want to perform a plasmonic simulation in COMSOL to replicate this paper. But I am not able to find any support for this type of simulation, where NV centers are considered as dipoles whose simulations are studied to some extent.

Is there any relevant materials explaining how these type of [simulations](https://www.comsol.com/paper/plasmon-enhanced-fluorescence-characteristics-government-by-selecting-the-right-64931) can be performed? I am open to anything that is done on Lumerical and don't need to specifically use COMSOL.

##### References

1. Gao, X.; Jiang, B.; Llacsahuanga Allcca, A. E.; Shen, K.; Sadi, M. A.; Solanki, A. B.; Ju, P.; Xu, Z.; Upadhyaya, P.; Chen, Y. P.; Bhave, S. A.; Li, T. High-Contrast Plasmonic-Enhanced Shallow Spin Defects in Hexagonal Boron Nitride for Quantum Sensing. Nano Letters, 2021, 21, 7708–7714. https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.nanolett.1c02495.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to add the link. Welcome to MMSE :)

Comment: yeah sorry for the inconvenience , added the links

Answer (score 1):

https://www.comsol.com/blogs/modeling-surface-plasmon-polaritons-in-comsol/ in the last paragraph of this blog there is a answer but i am not able to reach to it. what boundary conditions to use when combining a metal and a dipole
[image: I have added one dipole here but the effective field is not changing]

Comment: what do you mean "I am not able to reach it?". 
Also you seem to asking another question in the answer : "What boundary conditions to use when combining a metal and a dipole". Please ask new questions in a separate new post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @VandanRevanur If you refer to the link closely , you will know i am asking the same problem here. The initial problem was to find a probable simulation for spin defects in HBN coupled with plasmonic structures. I figured out in some papers they have done it with dipoles , so i tried with dipole but i am confused about the boundary conditions here , for " and by I am not able to reach " i meant i am not able to find the desired solution , i. e the photo luminescence increment due to plasmonic integration

Comment: @Subham please add this clarification in your answer.